# Not variable depending integral

Tags: calculus

I am interested in a certain integral in which although a variable exist the result is independent of that variable. More specifically, $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(tx)}{x}\,\mathrm dx$$ is equal to $\pi/2$. So why does this result not depend on $t$? I mean it may but I kind of don't know why.
Also for any integrand of the form $\int_0^\infty\frac{f(tx)}{x}\,\mathrm dx$ I think it never becomes depending on $t$. Is this true?

Comment: Have you tried substituting x by x/t?

Comment: Yes actually in a way i think . That integrand dx/x can be written as $\frac{d(tx)}{tx}$ andtjis would give non dependence i guess but if we dont do that, icant seea reason why it doesn’t depend on t , since if we taylored for example there must be t terms i guess , although there is infinity , idk rly.

Comment: So maybe following idea might help for some intuition: For some function $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$, plot $f(x)/x$ on some interval $(0,A)$ and compare to the plot of $f(tx)/x=t\cdot (f(tx)/(tx))$ on $(0,A/t)$. You will see, that the second plot is something like "$t$ times the function from the first plot squeezed on an interval with length $A/t$". This may help with the intuition. 

For computation: For some diffeomorphism $\phi:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ and $g:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ it holds $\int_{\phi(0)}^{\phi(\infty)}g(x)dx=\int_0^{\infty}\phi'(x)g(\phi(x))dx$.

Comment: Is there a much elementary explanation, I haven’t learned about diffeomorphisms , and also I didn’t quite get what you mean

Comment: But i should say that for some functions variable dependance is “preserved”

Comment: Just plot your integrand for $t=1$ on $[0,10]$ and compare this to a plot of your integrand with $t=2$ on $[0,5]$. Then you should see what I mean.

You do not need to know diffeomorphisms, just integrate by substitution the way you learned it.

Comment: New functions with useful properties can be constructed this way. See Laplace Transforms : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform

Comment: See this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ckrofc1idg) using the suggested substitution. It becomes just the t=1 special integral case.

Comment: I would say it's because $\displaystyle{\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(tx)}{x}\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(tx)}{tx}\,\mathrm d(tx)=\int_0^\infty f(tx)\,\mathrm d(tx)}$ and also beause $t\cdot\infty=\infty$ and $t\cdot0=0$

Comment: @KayK. , there is also another integral in which the so called t*$\inf$ can be used but the answer is a function of a variable tho